# Why this weird code works?

Tags: c++

I got the this:

```
int main(){
    int Array[] = { 10, 20, 30 };
    cout << -2[Array] << endl;
    system("Pause");
    return 0;

}
```

The output is:

> -30

I want to know why the output is -30 and why causes this undefined behavior?

does anyone knows?

Comment: It doesn't "work". It invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: thanks for the correction, I'll edit the question!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [With C arrays, why is it the case that a\[5\] == 5\[a\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/with-c-arrays-why-is-it-the-case-that-a5-5a)

Comment: @Gene: There's no undefined behavior here.

Comment: @user657267 @Gene It's `-(2[Array])` not `(-2)[Array]`

Comment: @user657267 "Array[-2] " doesn't produce the same behaviour.

Comment: @Gene: No it doesn't.

Comment: Good catch. You're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly simple.

First, let's analyse the expression:

```
-2[Array]
```

is

```
-(2[Array])
```

Now `a[b]` is `*(a+b)` and since addition is commutative this is also `*(b+a)` i.e. `Array[2]`.

`Array[2]` is `30`; `-Array[2]` is `-30`. Thus, `-2[Array]` is also `-30`.

I sincerely hope you do not intend to use this in production code.

Comment: Thanks!  haha no I won't it was just a doubt I had.

Answer (score 3):

`-2[Array]` is parsed as `-(2[Array])`, since subscripting has higher precedence than unary minus.

Now, [`2[Array]` is just a weird way to write `Array[2]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/381549/214671), so you get `-Array[2]`, i.e. -30. No undefined behavior is involved in the whole expression.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, the following statement is true:

```
a[5] == 5[a]
```

This is because the syntax using `[]` is converted to:

```
*(a + 5)
```

E.g.

```
a[5] == *(a + 5)
```

Which means that

```
5[a] == *(5 + a)
```

Thus the notation `-2[Array]` is converted to `- *(2 + Array)`.

Answer (score 0):

It applies the unary operator (-, minus sign) to pointer incremented by the value outside of [] thus: `- *(2 + Array)`. You can check it out by removing the minus sign, thus applying + unary operator. I would NOT recommend using this syntax.